# set a JTextField width in maner to wrap a given text

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextfield

I have an uneditable and disabled `JtextField` in which I will put a `String` obtained after requesting a Database, and I want that this `JtextField` wraps All my String.

I saw the `setColumn()` and `setSize()` methods but I don't know first my `String` length.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- JTextFields can only display a single line of text, period.
- If you need a simple text component that wraps text, use a JTextArea.
- Set its columns and rows.
- Put it into a JScrollPane (if you feel the text will go beyond the number of rows specified).
- Call `setLineWrap(true)` on it
- Call `setWrapStyleWord(true)` on it.

---

**Edit**
You ask about resizing the JTextField as text is being added or removed. I suppose that you could always override a JTextField's `getPreferredSize()` method, and revalidate/repaint its container on any change in text, but doing so does carry risk.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class VaryingTextFieldSize {
   protected static final int GAP = 5;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JTextField textField = new JTextField(1) {
         @Override
         public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension superPref = super.getPreferredSize();
            FontMetrics fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
            String text = getText();
            if (text.length() > 0) {
               int width = fontMetrics.charsWidth(text.toCharArray(), 0, text.length()) + GAP;
               return new Dimension(width, superPref.height);
            }
            return superPref;
         }
      };
      textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
         @Override
         public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            reSize();
         }

         @Override
         public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            reSize();
         }

         @Override
         public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            reSize();
         }

         private void reSize() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                  Container container = textField.getParent();
                  container.revalidate();
                  container.repaint();
               }
            });
         }
      });
      JPanel enclosingPanel = new JPanel();
      enclosingPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
      enclosingPanel.add(textField);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, enclosingPanel);
   }
}
```

Comment: I just have one line of text, not a multiline text

Comment: @RiadSaadi: yes, but your post states that you want a multi-line display of this single line. Again, a JTextField cannot do this but a JTextArea can. Your call.

Comment: maybe I did not explain well, I am sorry but what I want is for example  for editing "hello world" my jtextField will be just with the width to write "Hello world", and if I want to write "hello every body of the world", my jtextField will be larger than the first case but just to wrap the sentense "hello every body of the world".

Comment: @RiadSaadi: so ... you want your JTextField to resize as you're *typing* text into it?

Comment: how to do this please?